# Running several tasks together reporting progress ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm stumped to the best approach here, in simple terms we have the following process:

1. User uploads a file, this can be anything
2. If it's a video we use ffMpeg to convert to mp4, if it's an image, doc, pdf, etc. we do nothing but save the file
3. Once any conversion is completed we upload to Azure blob storage

We have small jQuery plugin which shows the progress of the file upload but once it reaches 100% we could still have a lot more work to do.

What is the best option we have here to within the Mvc action start a task which does this work allowing the response to return and then begin polling for updates from the view using jQuery.

As an aside we have a windows service which runs in the background which we may get to do the conversion using ffMpeg and allow the user to continue while the file is processed but for other file types we would want to do the upload to the server and then to azure in one go.

What would be the best approach here?

We are using latest versions of .net, Mvc, etc.